# Arithmetic functions and dirichlet products

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let N, $\tau$ and $\sigma$ be the arithmetic functions defined by 
N(n) = n,
$\tau$(n) = the number of divisors of n,i.e $\tau$(n) = $\sum_{d|n}$1, 
$\sigma$(n) = the sum of divisors of n ,i.e $\sigma$ (n) = $\sum_{d|n}d$, 
for all n, respectively. Show that $\sigma$ = $\varphi$ * $\tau$ and $\varphi$ * $\sigma$ = N * N, where * is the Dirichlet product

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!!!

Comment: What is $\varphi?$

Comment: @mathmax it's Euler's totient function, number of positive integers less than or equal to n that are relatively prime to n.

Comment: Try using the fact that the multiplicative arithmetic functions with the Dirichletproduct are an abelian group.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I(n)=1$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$.
It is known that $\sigma=I\ast N$ and that $(\varphi\ast I)(n)=\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)=n=N(n)$ and therefore $\varphi\ast I=N$. 
We now see $\varphi\ast\sigma=\varphi\ast( I\ast N)=(\varphi\ast I)\ast N=N\ast N$.
About the other equality: Are you sure it's right? We have $\varphi(n)<n$ and $(N\ast\tau)(n)=\sum_{ab=n}N(a)\tau(b)\geq N(n)\tau(1)=n$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I'm quite sure it isn't: $\varphi(7)=6\neq 9=1\cdot 2+7\cdot 1=N(1)\tau(7)+N(7)\tau(1)=\sum_{ab=7}N(a)\tau(b)=(N\ast\tau)(7)$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!
Yes, it's correct, I just figured it out: We have I*I =$\tau$, then $\varphi$*$\tau$ = $\varphi$*I*I = N*I = $\sum_{d|n}$N(d)I(n/d) = $\sum_{d|n}$d = $\sigma$(n)

Comment: I am sorry, I put a completely wrong equation in the question. I'll edit it. You are right what I had is wrong